# Peripheral devices connection (COM connection) problem with Win 11

Tags: serial-port, pyserial, windows-11, peripherals

After upgrading to Windows 11 I realize that there is no COM-Port to connect to, as it has become legacy software. And now I cannot find my device connecting through a USB port anymore
[image]

As I try to install the driver again, there was errors. Seems like some software to install driver is missing. It also said that even if the driver is installed, they might not be installed correctly.
[image]

And now when I try to connect my device and use pyserial on it it can not recognize any ports free to use. When I connect my device, it seems that they don't appear at Ports(COM and LPT) anymore, but instead in in Universal Serial Bus Controller. Still pyserial have problem to find available COM and my peripheral devices also cannot be found(As I think they often try to find COM port to connect to) What can I do to solve this? Please specify any clarification if you find my question somewhat misleading. Thank you in advance and have a great week!